# Cant go from one activity to another

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am very new to android development and i have designed a very simple app from which when i press one button it takes me to another activity but whenever i press the button my app crashes. i dont know what is wrong i know my code is right because its same everywhere on the internet. Kindly help
Thanks in advance. here is my code

ActivityMain.java

```
    package com.dreamfighter.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{
Button b1;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    }

    public void clickme(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,second.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

**Activity_Main.xml**

```
<

?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.dreamfighter.myapplication.MainActivity"
    android:background="#8e2424"
    >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="134dp"
    android:onClick="clickme"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**second.java**

```
    package com.dreamfighter.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class second extends AppCompatActivity{
Button b2;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    }
    public void clck(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(second.this,MainActivity.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**asd.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#26b891" >

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click me Now"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="332dp"
    android:onClick="clck" />
```

I am getting this error

> 08-21 14:05:12.814 19829-19829/com.dreamfighter.myapplication
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 19829 SIG: 9 08-21 14:05:57.944
>   20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication I/art: Late-enabling
>   -Xcheck:jni 08-21 14:05:57.998 20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication W/System: ClassLoader
>   referenced unknown path:
>   /data/app/com.dreamfighter.myapplication-1/lib/arm64 08-21
>   14:05:58.149 20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication W/System:
>   ClassLoader referenced unknown path:
>   /data/app/com.dreamfighter.myapplication-1/lib/arm64 08-21
>   14:05:58.157 20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication
>   D/ActivityThread: BIND_APPLICATION handled : 0 /
>   AppBindData{appInfo=ApplicationInfo{2b96c39
>   com.dreamfighter.myapplication}} 08-21 14:05:58.157
>   20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication V/ActivityThread: Handling
>   launch of ActivityRecord{502a27e token=android.os.BinderProxy@b15c3df
>   {com.dreamfighter.myapplication/com.dreamfighter.myapplication.MainActivity}}
>   startsNotResumed=false 08-21 14:05:58.212
>   20224-20233/com.dreamfighter.myapplication I/System: FinalizerDaemon:
>   finalize objects = 1 08-21 14:05:58.266
>   20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication V/ActivityThread:
>   ActivityRecord{502a27e token=android.os.BinderProxy@b15c3df
>   {com.dreamfighter.myapplication/com.dreamfighter.myapplication.MainActivity}}:
>   app=android.app.Application@8bb92f5,
>   appName=com.dreamfighter.myapplication,
>   pkg=com.dreamfighter.myapplication,
>   comp={com.dreamfighter.myapplication/com.dreamfighter.myapplication.MainActivity},
>   dir=/data/app/com.dreamfighter.myapplication-1/base.apk 08-21
>   14:05:58.346 20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication W/art: Before
>   Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter
>   android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter,
>   android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode)
>   would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable 08-21 14:05:58.353
>   20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication D/Resources:
>   resEntryNameFinal = com_dreamfighter_myapplication_abc_vector_test
>   08-21 14:05:58.370 20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication
>   E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed! 08-21 14:05:58.370
>   20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication D/PhoneWindow: XUI_SystemUI
>   isAutoChangeXUI:true, mStatusBarColor: -13615201, mNavigationBarColor:
>   -16777216 08-21 14:05:58.370 20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication D/PhoneWindow: XUI_SystemUI
>   ,Color.brightness(mStatusBarColor):false,Color.brightness(mNavigationBarColor)
>   :false 08-21 14:05:58.370 20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication
>   D/PhoneWindow: XUI_SystemUI isDarkStatusBar:false, isDarkNavBar:
>   false,View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR :16 08-21 14:05:58.420
>   20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication D/Resources:
>   resEntryNameFinal = com_dreamfighter_myapplication_colorPrimary 08-21
>   14:05:58.421 20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication D/Resources:
>   resEntryNameFinal = com_dreamfighter_myapplication_colorPrimary 08-21
>   14:05:58.505 20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication D/Resources:
>   Add /mnt/sdcard/BuildRes.apk cookie = 4 08-21 14:05:58.515
>   20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication V/ActivityThread:
>   Performing resume of ActivityRecord{502a27e
>   token=android.os.BinderProxy@b15c3df
>   {com.dreamfighter.myapplication/com.dreamfighter.myapplication.MainActivity}}
>   08-21 14:05:58.533 20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication
>   D/ActivityThread: ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{502a27e
>   token=android.os.BinderProxy@b15c3df
>   {com.dreamfighter.myapplication/com.dreamfighter.myapplication.MainActivity}}
>   08-21 14:05:58.534 20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication
>   V/ActivityThread: Resume ActivityRecord{502a27e
>   token=android.os.BinderProxy@b15c3df
>   {com.dreamfighter.myapplication/com.dreamfighter.myapplication.MainActivity}}
>   started activity: false, hideForNow: false, finished: false 08-21
>   14:05:58.534 20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication V/PhoneWindow:
>   DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4 ,Parent =null, this
>   =com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{52ffb18 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0} 08-21 14:05:58.539
>   20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication D/WindowClient: Add to
>   mViews: com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{52ffb18
>   I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}, this =
>   android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@f2d548e 08-21 14:05:58.540
>   20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Dumper
>   init 4 threads <0x7f722dab40> 08-21 14:05:58.540
>   20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer:
>    is running. 08-21 14:05:58.542
>   20224-20247/com.dreamfighter.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Use
>   EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: false 08-21 14:05:58.542
>   20224-20247/com.dreamfighter.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer:
>   CanvasContext() 0x7f6b015000 08-21 14:05:58.553
>   20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication I/[MALI][Gralloc]:
>   [+]r_hnd(0x7f63aab8c0), client(31), share_fd(30) 08-21 14:05:58.553
>   20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication D/GraphicBuffer: register,
>   handle(0x7f63aab8c0) (w:1216 h:2048 s:1216 f:0x1 u:0x000100) 08-21
>   14:05:58.555 20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication
>   D/ViewRootImpl: hardware acceleration is enabled, this =
>   ViewRoot{9e474af
>   com.dreamfighter.myapplication/com.dreamfighter.myapplication.MainActivity,ident
>   = 0} 08-21 14:05:58.560 20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication V/ActivityThread: Resuming ActivityRecord{502a27e
>   token=android.os.BinderProxy@b15c3df
>   {com.dreamfighter.myapplication/com.dreamfighter.myapplication.MainActivity}}
>   with isForward=true 08-21 14:05:58.560
>   20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication V/PhoneWindow: DecorView
>   setVisiblity: visibility = 0 ,Parent =ViewRoot{9e474af
>   com.dreamfighter.myapplication/com.dreamfighter.myapplication.MainActivity,ident
>   = 0}, this =com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{52ffb18 V.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0} 08-21 14:05:58.560
>   20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication V/ActivityThread:
>   Scheduling idle handler for ActivityRecord{502a27e
>   token=android.os.BinderProxy@b15c3df
>   {com.dreamfighter.myapplication/com.dreamfighter.myapplication.MainActivity}}
>   08-21 14:05:58.560 20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication
>   D/ActivityThread: ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 /
>   ActivityRecord{502a27e token=android.os.BinderProxy@b15c3df
>   {com.dreamfighter.myapplication/com.dreamfighter.myapplication.MainActivity}}
>   08-21 14:05:58.583 20224-20247/com.dreamfighter.myapplication
>   D/OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0x7f6b015000 initialize
>   window=0x7f786df010,
>   title=com.dreamfighter.myapplication/com.dreamfighter.myapplication.MainActivity
>   08-21 14:05:58.583 20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication
>   D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x7f786df000) 08-21
>   14:05:58.587 20224-20247/com.dreamfighter.myapplication
>   I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4 08-21 14:05:58.590
>   20224-20247/com.dreamfighter.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Created
>   EGL context (0x7f7257d200) 08-21 14:05:58.592
>   20224-20247/com.dreamfighter.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: Get
>   enable program binary service property (1) 08-21 14:05:58.592
>   20224-20247/com.dreamfighter.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer:
>   Initializing program atlas... 08-21 14:05:58.592
>   20224-20247/com.dreamfighter.myapplication D/ProgramBinary/Service:
>   BpProgramBinaryService.getFileDescriptor 08-21 14:05:58.593
>   20224-20247/com.dreamfighter.myapplication D/ProgramBinary/Service:
>   BpProgramBinaryService.getProgramMapLen 08-21 14:05:58.593
>   20224-20247/com.dreamfighter.myapplication D/ProgramBinary/Service:
>   BpProgramBinaryService.getProgramMapArray 08-21 14:05:58.593
>   20224-20247/com.dreamfighter.myapplication D/ProgramBinary/Service:
>   BpProgramBinaryService.getProgramBinaryLen 08-21 14:05:58.593
>   20224-20247/com.dreamfighter.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: Program
>   binary detail: Binary length is 169616, program map length is 152.
>   08-21 14:05:58.594 20224-20247/com.dreamfighter.myapplication
>   I/OpenGLRenderer: Succeeded to mmap program binaries. File descriptor
>   is 38, and path is /dev/ashmemc. 08-21 14:05:58.594
>   20224-20247/com.dreamfighter.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: No need
>   to use file discriptor anymore, close fd(38). 08-21 14:05:58.594
>   20224-20247/com.dreamfighter.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer:
>   Initializing program cache from 0x7f7c18bbb8, size = 4 08-21
>   14:05:58.596 20224-20247/com.dreamfighter.myapplication
>   D/OpenGLRenderer: -- init (key = 0x0000000000000000) 08-21
>   14:05:58.598 20224-20247/com.dreamfighter.myapplication
>   D/OpenGLRenderer: -- init (key = 0x0000000800000003) 08-21
>   14:05:58.599 20224-20247/com.dreamfighter.myapplication
>   D/OpenGLRenderer: -- init (key = 0x0000001000500040) 08-21
>   14:05:58.600 20224-20247/com.dreamfighter.myapplication
>   D/OpenGLRenderer: -- init (key = 0x0000003800000000) 08-21
>   14:05:58.602 20224-20247/com.dreamfighter.myapplication D/Surface:
>   Surface::connect(this=0x7f786df000,api=1) 08-21 14:05:58.603
>   20224-20247/com.dreamfighter.myapplication W/libEGL:
>   [ANDROID_RECORDABLE] format: 1 08-21 14:05:58.604
>   20224-20247/com.dreamfighter.myapplication D/mali_winsys:
>   new_window_surface returns 0x3000 08-21 14:05:58.647
>   20224-20247/com.dreamfighter.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer:
>   CacheTexture 2 upload: x, y, width height = 0, 0, 145, 180 08-21
>   14:05:58.651 20224-20247/com.dreamfighter.myapplication
>   I/[MALI][Gralloc]: [+]r_hnd(0x7f61e963c0), client(31), share_fd(39)
>   08-21 14:05:58.651 20224-20247/com.dreamfighter.myapplication
>   D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x7f61e963c0) (w:720 h:1280 s:720
>   f:0x1 u:0x000b00) 08-21 14:05:58.653
>   20224-20247/com.dreamfighter.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer:
>   ProgramCache save to disk, size = 4 08-21 14:05:58.657
>   20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication V/InputMethodManager:
>   onWindowFocus: null softInputMode=288 first=true flags=#81810100 08-21
>   14:05:58.657 20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication
>   V/InputMethodManager: START INPUT:
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{52ffb18 V.E......
>   R.....ID 0,0-720,1280} ic=null
>   tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@b24ea43 controlFlags=#104
>   08-21 14:05:58.671 20224-20247/com.dreamfighter.myapplication
>   I/[MALI][Gralloc]: [+]r_hnd(0x7f61e96460), client(31), share_fd(41)
>   08-21 14:05:58.671 20224-20247/com.dreamfighter.myapplication
>   D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x7f61e96460) (w:720 h:1280 s:720
>   f:0x1 u:0x000b00) 08-21 14:06:00.489
>   20224-20247/com.dreamfighter.myapplication I/[MALI][Gralloc]:
>   [+]r_hnd(0x7f61e96500), client(31), share_fd(42) 08-21 14:06:00.489
>   20224-20247/com.dreamfighter.myapplication D/GraphicBuffer: register,
>   handle(0x7f61e96500) (w:720 h:1280 s:720 f:0x1 u:0x000b00) 08-21
>   14:06:00.505 20224-20247/com.dreamfighter.myapplication
>   I/[MALI][Gralloc]: [+]r_hnd(0x7f61e96640), client(31), share_fd(43)
>   08-21 14:06:00.505 20224-20247/com.dreamfighter.myapplication
>   D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x7f61e96640) (w:720 h:1280 s:720
>   f:0x1 u:0x000b00) 08-21 14:06:00.519
>   20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication V/SettingsInterface:
>   invalidate [system]: current 306 != cached 0 08-21 14:06:00.521
>   20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication D/ActivityThread:
>   holder:android.app.IActivityManager$ContentProviderHolder@f38af4a,
>   holder.provider:android.content.ContentProviderProxy@dc75ebb 08-21
>   14:06:00.525 20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication
>   D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM 08-21 14:06:00.526
>   20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   Process: com.dreamfighter.myapplication, PID: 20224
>                                                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for
>   android:onClick
>                                                                                       at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5274)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21543)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
>                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5274) 
>                                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21543) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
>                                                                                    Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find
>   explicit activity class
>   {com.dreamfighter.myapplication/com.dreamfighter.myapplication.second};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1805)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1523)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3968)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3920)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:856)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4259)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4227)
>                                                                                       at
>   com.dreamfighter.myapplication.MainActivity.clickme(MainActivity.java:21)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5274) 
>                                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21543) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)  08-21
>   14:06:02.510 20224-20224/com.dreamfighter.myapplication I/Process:
>   Sending signal. PID: 20224 SIG: 9

Comment: change method name `click` to `clickme` as you declare in layout and also check `SecondActivty` is registered or not on `menofest.xml`.

Comment: have you declared second activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: read this line in your logcat     Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.dreamfighter.myapplication/com.dreamfighter.myapplication.second}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [...have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699192/have-you-declared-this-activity-in-your-androidmanifest-xml)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Activity Declaration in AndroidManifest.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122386/activity-declaration-in-androidmanifest-xml)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36502277/getting-illegalstateexception-on-button-click check this

Answer (score 1):

Add your `second.java` in your Menifest file;

```
 <activity
        android:name=".second"
        android:label="@string/second"
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have declared the activity in your manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".second"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

Use the theme which you are using in your app.

Answer (score 1):

Change this button layout with your layout, or you can replace only
   `android:onClick="clicme"` with `android:onClick="clickme"`:

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginTop="134dp"
            android:onClick="clickme"
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check AndroidManifest.xml file. need to register each activity in AndroidManifest.xml file before use.

Here you need to register second.java in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

**change this in your second activity by mistake your set the setContentView of main activity in your second activity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);// change here
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
}
```

**and make sure your added your activity in manifest file**

```
 <activity
    android:name=".second"
    android:label="@string/second"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Interface `OnClickListener` try this `public class second extends AppCompatActivity` instant of use `public class second extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener`

```
     public class second extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener {
        Button b2;

            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
                b2.setOnClickListener(this);

            }
          }

         @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                switch (view.getId())
                {
                    case R.id.button2:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(second.this,MainActivity.class);            
                        startActivity(intent);

                }

}
```

I hope this will help you,

Answer (score 0):

Declare your second activity in manifest.

```
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity"/>
```