# Android - java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException crash in my app

Tags: java, android, crash, stack-trace, google-play-console

I'm new to this programming world. I made a small app (Size of apk file is 1.74MB) for the first time and launched it to google play few months ago. I tested my app(before launching to the play store) with all the OS versions using the android studio emulators and it worked well with all those versions. Now I have received 26 crash reports from 7 users and I have no idea about what has gone wrong. I checked each line in my app individually according to the stack traces which are given in the crash reports and realized that those lines were created by the app itself. I searched all over the internet during the past week to find a solution for this issue.

***98 people have installed this app and I have received crash reports only from 7 of them. Is it possible to occur this kind of a crash due to bad memory management(less free space, too many installed apps etc.) of those 7 devices?***

Here's a screenshot from my play console.
[image: console]

---

Here are the stack traces from those 7 devices. I have personally used this app in a Samsung Galaxy J7 prime and it worked well with it. **But here there's a crash report from same type of a device too.**

```
Oct 20, 1:10 PM on app version 2
Samsung Galaxy J7 Prime (on7xelte), 3072MB RAM, Android 6.0
Report 6 of 6

java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick (AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
  at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:5721)
  at android.widget.TextView.performClick (TextView.java:10931)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:22620)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7409)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1230)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick (AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
```

---

```
Nov 3, 12:45 PM on app version 2
Huawei Y3II (HWLUA-L6735), 1024MB RAM, Android 5.1
Report 1 of 2

java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick (AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
  at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:4848)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:20270)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:815)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:104)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:194)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5674)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:963)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:758)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick (AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
```

---

```
Oct 25, 9:52 AM on app version 2
Samsung Galaxy Note3 (hltektt), 3072MB RAM, Android 5.0
Report 2 of 2

java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick (AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
  at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:5194)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:20903)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:145)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5942)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1399)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1194)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick (AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
```

---

```
Nov 11, 3:16 PM on app version 2
Oppo CPH1701 (CPH1701), 3072MB RAM, Android 6.0
Report 1

java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick (AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
  at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:5231)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:21240)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:179)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5730)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:791)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:681)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick (AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
```

---

```
Oct 30, 10:47 PM on app version 2
OnePlus OnePlus3T (OnePlus3T), 6144MB RAM, Android 7.1
Report 15

java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick (AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
  at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:5669)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:22549)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6321)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:886)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:776)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick (AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
```

---

```
Oct 20, 4:46 PM on app version 2
HTC One A9 (htc_hiaeuhl), 2048MB RAM, Android 7.0
Report 17 of 18

java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick (AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
  at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:5637)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:22396)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:173)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6459)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:938)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:828)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick (AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
```

---

```
Nov 4, 1:58 PM on app version 2
Samsung Galaxy J2(2016) (j2xlte), 1536MB RAM, Android 6.0
Report 1

java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick (AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
  at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:5716)
  at android.widget.TextView.performClick (TextView.java:10926)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:22596)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7325)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1230)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick (AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
```

---

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36502277/getting-illegalstateexception-on-button-click. Check if `ActivityNotFoundException` is at the root of this. Play console doesn't seem to have the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @IshitaSinha 98 people have installed this app and I have received crash reports only from 7 of them. Is it possible to occur this kind of a crash due to bad memory management(less free space, too many installed apps etc.) of  those 7 devices?

Comment: Sure. Sometimes if the activity gets killed and an onClick is called on a destroyed activity, it can throw this kind of exception because it can't find the original context of the view the click was performed on.